# Row based summary calculations

Tags: r

xx

```
head(xx,1)
     Sport    variable 2012.07.01 2012.07.02 2012.07.03 2012.07.04 2012.07.05 2012.07.06 2012.07.07 2012.07.08 2012.07.09 2012.07.10 2012.07.11 2012.07.12 2012.07.13 2012.07.14 2012.07.15 2012.07.16 2012.07.17
1 Soccer Likes         13         13         14         12         11         11         NA          9         16         11         12         15         10         NA         13          9         10
  2012.07.18 2012.07.19 2012.07.20 2012.07.21 2012.07.22 2012.07.23 2012.07.24 2012.07.25 2012.07.26 2012.07.27 2012.07.28 2012.07.29 2012.07.30 2012.07.31 2012.08.01 2012.08.02 2012.08.03 2012.08.04 2012.08.05
1         16         10         17         NA         10         15         14         11         11         13         NA         13         26        987        898        162        146         NA        257
  2012.08.06 2012.08.07 2012.08.08 2012.08.09 2012.08.10 2012.08.11 2012.08.12 2012.08.13 2012.08.14 2012.08.15 2012.08.16 2012.08.17 2012.08.18 2012.08.19 2012.08.20 2012.08.21 2012.08.22 2012.08.23 2012.08.24
1        370        443        490        612        646         NA        311        371        432        512        610        734         NA       1002        931        886        190        317        386
  2012.08.25 2012.08.26 2012.08.27 2012.08.28 2012.08.29 2012.08.30 2012.08.31 2012.09.01 2012.09.02 2012.09.03 2012.09.04 2012.09.05 2012.09.06 2012.09.07 2012.09.08 2012.09.09 2012.09.10 2012.09.11 2012.09.12
1         NA        586        812        904        863        941        922         NA        150        146        175        132        254        330         NA        198        281        254        316
  2012.09.13 2012.09.14 2012.09.15 2012.09.16 2012.09.17 2012.09.18 2012.09.19 2012.09.20 2012.09.21 2012.09.22 2012.09.23 2012.09.24 2012.09.25 2012.09.26 2012.09.27 2012.09.28 2012.09.29 2012.09.30 2012.10.01
1        416        594         NA        668        745        972        984        885        496         NA        687        734        767        832        965        934         NA        200        225
  2012.10.02 2012.10.03 2012.10.04 2012.10.05 2012.10.06 2012.10.07 2012.10.08 2012.10.09 2012.10.10 2012.10.11       SD Mean        Max   Min mean
1        219        181        198        229         NA        364        431        492        592        612 336.9102   NA soccer     9   NA
```

trying to calculate row standard deviation, mean, max, min etc per each row with the following formula:

```
transform(xx, SD=apply(xx,1, sd, na.rm = TRUE)) 
transform(xx, Mean=apply(xx,1, mean, na.rm = TRUE)) 
transform(xx, Max=apply(xx,1, max, na.rm = TRUE)) 
transform(xx, Min=apply(xx,1, min, na.rm = TRUE))
```

I dont think this is working since my first two columns are text rather than all numbers.

Is there a way to just calculate numbers in row based calculations?

Comment: When posting output from R, try setting `options(width = 70)` or some similar small number to avoid the wrapping that is taking place in the code block.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `[` to select the relevant variables as in:

```
set.seed(007)
X <- data.frame(matrix(sample(c(10:20, NA), 100, replace=TRUE), ncol=10))
sex <- sample(c('F', 'M'), 10, T)
reg <- sample(c('N', 'S', 'E', 'W'), 10, T)
DF <- cbind(sex, reg, X)
DF # this is your data.frame
       sex reg X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10
1    F   E NA 12 17 18 19 16 12 13 20  14
2    F   S 14 12 13 13 14 18 16 17 20  10
3    F   N 11 19 NA 12 19 19 19 20 12  20
4    F   E 10 11 20 12 15 17 18 17 18  12
5    M   E 12 15 NA 14 20 18 16 11 14  18
6    F   E 19 11 10 20 13 14 17 16 10  16
7    M   E 14 16 17 15 10 11 15 15 11  16
8    F   W NA 10 15 19 19 12 15 15 19  14
9    M   N 11 NA NA 20 20 14 14 17 14  19
10   F   W 15 13 14 15 NA 13 15 NA 15  12
```

As you can see the first to varibles are non-numeric. use `sapply(DF, class)` to see that.

Now using `[` as mentioned above you can choose all the numeric variables

```
DF[,-c(1,2)] # selecting all variables but 1 and 2
```

You can now perform your calculations on these varibles

```
transform(DF, SD=apply(DF[,-c(1,2)],1, sd, na.rm = TRUE))  # and so on
   sex reg X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10       SD
1    F   E NA 12 17 18 19 16 12 13 20  14 3.041381
2    F   S 14 12 13 13 14 18 16 17 20  10 3.020302
3    F   N 11 19 NA 12 19 19 19 20 12  20 3.865805
4    F   E 10 11 20 12 15 17 18 17 18  12 3.496029
5    M   E 12 15 NA 14 20 18 16 11 14  18 2.958040
6    F   E 19 11 10 20 13 14 17 16 10  16 3.596294
7    M   E 14 16 17 15 10 11 15 15 11  16 2.449490
8    F   W NA 10 15 19 19 12 15 15 19  14 3.201562
9    M   N 11 NA NA 20 20 14 14 17 14  19 3.356763
10   F   W 15 13 14 15 NA 13 15 NA 15  12 1.195229
```

Another alternative would be:

```
newDF <- DF[,sapply(DF, is.numeric)]
transform(DF, SD=apply(newDF,1, sd, na.rm = TRUE))
   sex reg X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10       SD
1    F   E NA 12 17 18 19 16 12 13 20  14 3.041381
2    F   S 14 12 13 13 14 18 16 17 20  10 3.020302
3    F   N 11 19 NA 12 19 19 19 20 12  20 3.865805
4    F   E 10 11 20 12 15 17 18 17 18  12 3.496029
5    M   E 12 15 NA 14 20 18 16 11 14  18 2.958040
6    F   E 19 11 10 20 13 14 17 16 10  16 3.596294
7    M   E 14 16 17 15 10 11 15 15 11  16 2.449490
8    F   W NA 10 15 19 19 12 15 15 19  14 3.201562
9    M   N 11 NA NA 20 20 14 14 17 14  19 3.356763
10   F   W 15 13 14 15 NA 13 15 NA 15  12 1.195229
```

I prefer this last one since you don't have to know which varible is numeric, R will select them for you.

### Edit

This would be a better approach

Define a function for basic stats

```
  Stats <- function(x){
      Mean <- mean(x, na.rm=TRUE)
      SD <- sd(x, na.rm=TRUE)
      Min <- min(x, na.rm=TRUE)
      Max <- max(x, na.rm=TRUE)
      return(c(Mean=Mean, SD=SD, Min=Min, Max=Max))
    }

    cbind(DF, t(apply(newDF,1, Stats))) # Where newDF is define as above 
   sex reg X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10     Mean       SD Min Max
1    F   E NA 12 17 18 19 16 12 13 20  14 15.66667 3.041381  12  20
2    F   S 14 12 13 13 14 18 16 17 20  10 14.70000 3.020302  10  20
3    F   N 11 19 NA 12 19 19 19 20 12  20 16.77778 3.865805  11  20
4    F   E 10 11 20 12 15 17 18 17 18  12 15.00000 3.496029  10  20
5    M   E 12 15 NA 14 20 18 16 11 14  18 15.33333 2.958040  11  20
6    F   E 19 11 10 20 13 14 17 16 10  16 14.60000 3.596294  10  20
7    M   E 14 16 17 15 10 11 15 15 11  16 14.00000 2.449490  10  17
8    F   W NA 10 15 19 19 12 15 15 19  14 15.33333 3.201562  10  19
9    M   N 11 NA NA 20 20 14 14 17 14  19 16.12500 3.356763  11  20
10   F   W 15 13 14 15 NA 13 15 NA 15  12 14.00000 1.195229  12  15
```

Comment: @Jiber, thank you for your help. I really appreciate it. This works for SD, I assume the samething should work for mean, max, min?

Comment: great help, wow. There is so much with R, it could be very frustrating.

Comment: I have One more question, I promise I will leave you alone. Now, I have bunch of headers with different dates and underneath, values pertaining to the dates. I calculated the mean, sd. I would like to calculate the outliers for each cell. Compare each cell to teh sd, how would I do that?

Comment: You can put it as a new question and show us what you've tried so far, but, roughly speaking if you want to use SD to compare values and find outliers you can set a threshold over which a single observation could be considered as outlier if this is the case `ifelse` and `sweep` would be good options.

Answer (score 8):

```
summary(t(xx))
```

`summary()` can obtain the statistics by columns, therefore use a `t()`.

Comment: The accepted answer is much longer, are you sure this is a complete answer? Could you please explain a little more how it works? Thank you!